# PHP REST API Token Expiration Flow

Tags: php, api, authentication, token, access-token

I am creating a REST API in PHP, and I am having some problems to understand the concept of what I have to do with the expired tokens. I have MYSQL and Json Web Tokens for the authentication part.

**DB STRUCTURE**

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(35) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(35) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `gender` enum('male','female') CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `email_verification` enum('unverified','verified','','') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'unverified',
  `updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `device_tokens` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `device_id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `device_version` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `token` text NOT NULL,
  `update` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**LOGIN**

I create a POST Request with the user and password, and if the validation is correct I return an access token (Json Web Token), that contains the following data:

> - email
> - name
> - user_creation_date
> - expiration time

**LOGOUT**
I create a POST Request with the access_token, device_type and user_id. But what happened if the token is already expired? I just deleted?

**ANOTHER END POINT**

```
for example 
/pets?id=1
```

I create a GET Request with the access_token, user_id, and xx_id, so before I return the data. I verify if the token is correct, and if the token corresponds to the user that is makeing the request. But, what happened if the token has expired? I create another one?. In the case that I have to return another unexpired token, should I logout the user and ask the password and email again?

I don't understand what is the best way to do this. In other posts that I created about authentication, many users recommended me to use a third party authentication system, but I want to develop it myself.

Thanks for all

Answer (score 3):

Usually if the token is expired you should remove it from database and logout the user. However, if the user is active it should be possible to extend the life time of the his access-token during his requests to your service. However, there is another approach when an additional parameter **refresh-token** is introduced. In this case the flow can look like:

1. User logins to your system. Two tokens **access and refresh** are generated.
2. User requests different endpoints and send only access-token.
3. Access-token is expired. User sends a refresh-token to extend life time of his session.
4. Refresh-token is invalid or expired then your system logouts the user.
5. Refresh-token is valid then access-token life time is extended.
6. User is happy and can continue using your service.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the help. So I create an access token and a refresh token and I send it to the client. The client stores both fields and when a request is made and the access-token is expired, the client must made another request with the refresh-token ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. However, you use different response codes in case the access-token is expired or it's invalid. If it's expired the client should send refresh-token. If it's invalid an user has to login again. @JIFT